# react-native SectionList How to scrollToTop by using scrollToLocation?

Tags: react-native

I can only scrollTo items or itemTitle by using this func, but I can't find a way to scrollToTop.
There are 5 params I can use below.

```
this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({
  sectionIndex: 0,
  itemIndex: -1,
  viewPosition: 1,
  viewOffset: 0,
  animated: true,
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you have to use `scrollTo` method of `ScrollView` for that. Ref:https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto

Comment: @AravindS yeah, but how can I use scrollTo method when I use SectionList?

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any api or func to scrollToTop by using SectionList. I can only calculate the `viewOffset` to scrollToTop.

`this.sectionHeaderHeight` is the height of the sectionListHeader (e.native.layout.height)

```
this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({
  sectionIndex: 0,
  itemIndex: 0,
  viewPosition: 0,
  viewOffset: this.sectionHeaderHeight,
  animated: true,
});
```

Answer (score -1):

add a function to scroll to the top:

```
scrollToTop() {
    this.scroll.scrollTo({x:0, y:0, animated: true})
}
```

In your ScrollView add:

```
<ScrollView
    ref={(f) => { this.scroll = f }}
>
.......
</ScrollView>
```

There after you can add maybe a floating button that calls scrollToTop function. Or you can even use it after setting state or whatever. eg:

```
setSomeState(something) {
    this.setState({ something }, () => this.scroll.scrollTo({x:0, y:0, animated: true }));
}
```

Comment: but I need to use scrollToTop in SectionList.

Comment: How about wrapping the sectionList in a ScrollView?